# PHP array_merge if not empty

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Trying to merge 4 arrays, but some may be empty at certain times.

```
$array_1 = array('something1', something2);
$array_2 = array('something3', something4);
$array_3 = array();
$array_4 = array('something1', something2);

$list = array_merge($array_1,$array_2,$array_3,$array_4);

print_r($list);
```

But if one of the arrays are empty, there will be an error.
I've been googling forever, but I can't find a solid simple answer on how to check for empty arrays before merging.

> Argument #2 is not an array

Or whichever array is empty is the argument number. How do I strip out empty arrays before merging?

Comment: if you make array of arrays of them, you can loop through it, perform multiple merges and do the empty() checks there

Comment: Would you have an example?

Comment: okay i made an answer, may or may not help

Comment: There is NO error with an empty array.  There is only an error if the arg is NOT an array.

Comment: merging an empty array is **NOT** an error.

Comment: Read your error/notice messages more carefully.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Okay here you go, this should do the trick (if you make array of the initial arrays):

```
$arrs = array();

$arrs[] = array('something1', something2);
$arrs[] = array('something3', something4);
$arrs[] = array();
$arrs[] = array('something1', something2);

$list = array();

foreach($arrs as $arr) {
    if(is_array($arr)) {
        $list = array_merge($list, $arr);
    }
}

print_r($list);
```

Comment: This worked perfect, never thought of making the variables arrays and looping through. Thanks!

Comment: isn't $list empty on the first iteration?

Comment: @Yada tbh I dont think array_merge has a problem with empty array, I suspect David tried to feed null or undefined variable into it.

Comment: `if(!empty($arr))` should be `if(is_array($arr))`. As others have pointed out, you need to ensure that it _is_ an array, it doesn't matter if it is empty.

Comment: Yes really good but you should avoid empty array as well, if (is_array($arr)&&!empty($arr)) {
                $list = array_merge($list, $arr);
            } , got problem in json_encode. :)

Answer (score 19):

There is NO error with an empty array. There is only an error if the arg is NOT an array.

You could check `is_array()` or:

```
$list = array_merge(
(array)$array_1,
(array)$array_2,
(array)$array_3,
(array)$array_4
);
```

Answer (score 5):

Array merge supports empty array()

Doc:

Example #3 Simple array_merge() example
https://www.php.net/array_merge

```
<?php
$array1 = array();
$array2 = array(1 => "data");
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
?>

Result
Array
(
    [0] => data
)
```

You are getting notice because something2, something4 should be quoted as string or $ as variable.

```
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant something2 - assumed 'something2'
```