# How do i properly add an element into an array depending on the elements have values or not in php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to do something as below :

```
$location1 = (isset($_POST['location1'])) ? $_POST['location1'] : null ;
$location2 = (isset($_POST['location2'])) ? $_POST['location2'] : null ;
$locations = array($location1, $location2);

print_r($locations);
```

here `print_r($locatios)` showing `Array ( [0] => location1 [1] => )` , an unnecessary index is being created if `$location2` is null. I want if `$location2` is null then i get just `Array ( [0] => location1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if statement will be better in this case.

```
$locations = array();

if (isset($_POST['location1'])) {
    $locations[] = $_POST['location1'];
}

if (isset($_POST['location2'])) {
    $locations[] = $_POST['location2'];
}
```

Comment: High-five for the same answer :P

Comment: This is the recommended way as of PHP 5.4

Comment: @TimLewis the reason `[]` is used is because `arraypush()` is using unnecessary function calls, its great for pushing large stacks but naff for individual elements.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that used a lot recently.

Comment: i don't think you need to declare $locations = array(); because when you're using $locations[] you are declaring it as an array aswell.

Comment: But you sholud, because there could be case when none of if statement will be `true`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$locations = array();

if(isset($_POST['location1']) {
    array_push($locations, $_POST['location1']);
}

if(isset($_POST['location2']) {
    array_push($locations, $_POST['location2']);
}

print_r($locations);
```

Your logic was still inputting `null` into the array, which is why that index is there.

Answer (score 1):

Name your form inputs with `[]`:

```
<input name="locations[]">
<input name="locations[]">
```

Then you're already getting them as needed:

```
$locations = $_POST['locations'];
```

Optionally: filter out empty submitted fields:

```
$locations = array_filter($_POST['locations']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try an `array_merge`:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

So:

```
 $locations = array_merge($location1, $location2);
```

And this question deals with the issue when one of the arrays is empty: [PHP array_merge if not empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131948/php-array-merge-if-not-empty)

By checking if it's array first before merging:

```
 if(is_array($location1)) {
```

Comment: array_merge() needs array parameters . $location1 and $location2 are not arrays