# Iterating over multidimensional array where some arrays might have no elements

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a $products array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1001
            [1] => 1002
        )

    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
    [6] => 
    [7] => 
)
```

I want to loop through it and create a one-level array comprised only of the non-empty array data like this:

```
$newArr = [
    [0] => 1001,
    [1] => 1002
]
```

My foreach loop that I thought would work throws an error (`'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()'`).

The foreach loop looks like this:

```
$idArr = [];
foreach($products as $value) {
    foreach ($value as $id) {
        echo $id . '<br>';
        $idArr[] = $id;
    }
}
```

The two values echo suggesting the code is correct, but it's not. I am unable to store the iterated $id value into `$idArr[]`.

If anyone can spot my error or errors, I would appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: replace `$products` with `array_filter($products)` inside your `foreach`.

Comment: Some of your original array have null elements... not empty arrays... then you must use the second foreach only if `$value` is not empty... then add `if (!empty($value)) { foreach($value as $id){} }`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change your code much, you can just skip the inner loop if there's no value.

```
$idArr = [];
foreach($products as $value) {
    if (!$value) continue;   // continue to next iteration without executing the inner loop
    foreach ($value as $id) {
        $idArr[] = $id;
    }
}
```

Or enclose the inner loop in an `if ($value) ...` block. However you like, as long as you're not trying to iterate arrays that aren't there.

Comment: I love your name! Thanks for ending my panic. It works! I found another way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131948/php-array-merge-if-not-empty)

Comment: Thanks :-) Since that other post solves your problem, I think you can flag your own question as a duplicate of it. (I'd prefer not to do that myself since I answered and my vote will close it instantly.)

Comment: It's subjective, but I don't think  it's a duplicate. In fact, your answer is concise, and therefore, at least in my mind, superior. Brevity wins. In addition, you showed me `continue` which I never knew. Great and unique answer.

Comment: Sure, that's fine, it's up to you. Just wanted to let you know, because most people don't realize it's possible to flag their own posts. I've closed a couple of my own questions after finding good duplicate answers. Many people also view duplicate closures as a negative thing, but it's really not. Your question just becomes a pointer to an answer that already exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arrayTest = [
        'country' => [
            'Russian Federation' => [
                'Region' => [
                    'Moscow',
                    'Moscow',
                    'Moscow'
                ],
                'Moscow', 
                'Moscow', 
                'Moscow'
            ],
            "United States of America" => [
                'Moscow', 
                'Moscow', 
                'Moscow'
            ],
            "China" => [
                'Moscow', 
                'Moscow', 
                'Moscow'
            ]
        ],

        'union' => [
            'Moscow', 
            'Moscow'
        ], 

        'status' => 1, 

        'age' => 34
    ];

$result = [];
array_walk_recursive($arrayTest, function ($item, $key) use (&$result) {
    $result[] = $item;    
});
print_r($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$idArr = array();
foreach($products as $value) {
    if(is_array($value)){
        foreach ($value as $id) {
                $idArr[] = $id;
         }
      }
 }
```

Comment: $value from first foreach loop is array so I didn’t understand why second foreach is wrong

Comment: `print_r([[], null])` is your friend here.

Comment: P.S. Now your `if(count($value)>0){` solution is not a solution at all, please study `print_r` output first.

Comment: P.P.S. Now your `if($id!=null)` is not required anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [PHP Spl RecursiveIteratorIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php)

```
$array = array(1,2,array(3,4, array(5,6,7), 8),[0=>1, 1=> [0=>null]], 9);
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($a));
foreach($it as $v) {
  echo $v, " ";
}
```

prints

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 9
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1320259/2693543) modified to suit your example